# Kate crashes while clicking Open

Tags: kate

I am running on Ubuntu 12.04 I recently noticed that Kate 4.8.4 which have been installed in my 64-bit PC is crashing whenever I try to open a file in it. It shows no problem when I open files via terminal.

It displays the following in the terminal while crashing.

```
trying to create local folder /home/myusername/.kde/tmp-MYPCNAME: Permission denied
trying to create local folder /home/myusername/.kde/socket-MYPCNAME: Permission denied
trying to create local folder /home/myusername/.kde/tmp-MYPCNAME: Permission denied
QFile::remove: Empty or null file name
kdeinit4: Aborting. bind() failed: Permission denied
Could not bind to socket '/home/myusername/.kde/socket-MYPCNAME/kdeinit4__0'
trying to create local folder /home/myusername/.kde/cache-MYPCNAME: Permission denied
trying to create local folder /home/myusername/.kde/share: Permission denied
kate(3237) fileModule: Failed to load configured file module "kfilemodule"
KCrash: Application 'kate' crashing...
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/home/myusername/.kde/socket-MYPCNAME/kdeinit4__0
Warning: connect() failed: : Permission denied
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi directly
trying to create local folder /home/myusername/.kde/cache-MYPCNAME: Permission denied
QFile::remove: Empty or null file name
drkonqi(3251)/KSharedDataCache KSharedDataCache::Private::mapSharedMemory: Failed to establish shared memory mapping, will fallback to private memory -- memory usage will increase
```

From the above I understand that this is a problem of user privileges. I checked running Kate from the terminal as root it works fine.

As I am new to linux can someone point me in a direction that could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the ownership of the .kde folder with these console commands:

```
cd ~
sudo chown -R yourusername .kde
```

Replace yourusername with your actual user name. You will be prompted for the sudo password.

This error usually happens as a result of running graphical programs (like `kate`) as `root` directly with `sudo`, which can cause `root` to create its own configuration files in your home directory (or effectively take ownership of the ones that are already there). Instead, a graphical `sudo` frontend, such as [`kdesudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/kdesudo.1.html) (or [`gksu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksu.1.html)/[`gksudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksudo.1.html)) should [always be used when running graphical programs as `root`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo).

Comment: That solved the issue. But isn't user the owner of his or her home folder ?

Comment: @mahesmohan I've expanded this answer with an explanation for how `root` can come to own files in users' home folders (and how to avoid this problem in the future).

Comment: Can someone edit this to replace the "yourusername" bit with `$USER`? Then it'll work as-is

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing a similar issue when running [Kexi](https://www.calligra.org/kexi/) on my Linux Mint 17.2 system:

```
...
kexi(9324) fileModule: Failed to load configured file module "kfilemodule"
KCrash: Application 'kexi' crashing...
...
```

The solution in my case (found [here](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/07/28/solution-for-crashing-kde-applications-on-linux-mint-17-1-cinnamon/)) was to manually install some KDE-specific packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins
```

Initially I thought this was a packaging issue specific to Kexi, but since it seems to affect multiple KDE applications, I guess it might be a KDE packaging problem.

Comment: I moved to Arch now. And I mostly use vi and sublime, so I really don't have the means to test your solution...

Comment: I appreciate that you were facing this problem years ago, but it seems that people (myself included) are still experiencing this, so I've posted an answer in case it helps others.

Comment: this worked for me for KCachegrind on Mint 17.3

Answer (score 0):

If Kate crashes when you try to open or save a file, try installing kdelibs5-plugins:

```
sudo apt-get install kdelibs5-plugins
```