# Kubuntu 15.10: Kate Crashes Immediately on Startup

Tags: kubuntu, kate, kde5

As soon as I start Kate, it immediately crashes with these lines:

```
No docs r (or the only) opened right now --> disable menu
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on KateMDI::ToolView "",
which already has a layout
No docs r (or the only) opened right now --> disable menu
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I start it with a file as an argument, it crashes with these:

```
No docs r (or the only) opened right now --> disable menu
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on KateMDI::ToolView "",
which already has a layout
No docs r (or the only) opened right now --> disable menu
No docs r (or the only) opened right now --> disable menu
stage #1: Collected 1 paths and 0 masks
stage #2: Collected 1 paths and 0 masks
stage #1: Collected 2 paths and 0 masks
stage #2: Collected 2 paths and 0 masks
stage #1: Collected 2 paths and 0 masks
stage #2: Collected 2 paths and 0 masks
The font for use in the terminal has not been matched exactly. Perhaps it
has not been found properly.
The font for use in the terminal has not been matched exactly. Perhaps it
has not been found properly.
stage #1: Collected 2 paths and 0 masks
stage #2: Collected 2 paths and 0 masks
No docs r (or the only) opened right now --> disable menu
No docs r (or the only) opened right now --> disable menu
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Things I've tried include reinstalling it (no change). Very strangely, if I run it as the root user under sudo, it actually starts up and works normally, although it looks absolutely horrendous (like it's running in the wrong resolution or something).

Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kate crashes while clicking Open](http://askubuntu.com/questions/167426/kate-crashes-while-clicking-open)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing kdelibs5-plugins:

```
sudo apt-get install kdelibs5-plugins
```

Comment: I don't think this is related to OP's issue.